# Override all users password in GitLab exception admin

Tags: security, gitlab

TL;DR -- How do I override all internal passwords for GitLab (non-admin, non-external) users so that they cannot change their password and must use SAML to login?

We have an internal GitLab server that is set to authenticate via SAML to an AD which has MFA enabled (Azure reverse proxy).

Security has found out that users are setting a local password in GitLab and getting around MFA and logging locally into the server.

They're asking me to remove the login screen completely.  I rather set an internal password for non-admin and non-external users, and somehow disable the password recovery (blocking email?).  Is that possible?

This is the closest thing I found but no easy way to script that as far as I can see.  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html